# Loading spatialite with python3's module under Windows

Tags: python, spatialite, windows, python-3, pip

I installed spatialite's Python module using pip:

`pip install spatialite`

I copied the mod_spatialite.dll found on https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/index.html into my windows/system32 folder (I have Python 3 32bits)

I have the error message

`spatialite.connection.LoadExtensionError: Failed to load SpatiaLite extension. Verify that your python module sqlite3 has load_extension support and check that libspatialite is installed. Tried extension names: mod_spatialite, mod_spatialite.so, mod_spatialite.dylib`

Comment: Have same error, did you find a solution?

Comment: I don't think I found a solution, I think I just installed debian on windows through WSL and worked from there. I tried asking on #python on freenode but got no relevant help. I recommend asking either on #winapi or through the spatialite mailinglist.